# Cannot start the recorder in silk4j

Tags: silktest

I'm just stepping into the automation testing tool Silk4J.

I followed the guide to start to record a test. However, every time I click the "Silk4J test", I get the same error:

> Failed to start recorder.
>   Reason:Failed to start /recorder/Silk Recorder.exe after 180 seconds

I searched for it for a long time but got nothing valuable.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What version of Silk Test are you using? Can you please try to use process explorer, to see if the `silkRecorder.exe` is actually started.

Comment: @tehlexx I can see the process "silkRecorder.exe" in the windows task manager.

Comment: @tehlexx the version is "Silk_Test_13.6_-_Silk4J_Web_Edition"

Comment: @tehlexx is there any log file from which I can get some details?

Comment: That's strange. Log files should be in `%APPDATA%\Silk\SilkTest\logs`.  Have you tried re-installing it? Maybe your installation got corrupted.

Comment: @tehlexx I checked the log dir but found nothing valued. I've tried re-installing for several times and I'm sure the process didn't get corrupted. BTW, I downloaded the installation package from this link:[link]https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/silk4j-web-edition I cannot download the latest version from borland website cos it required me to provide company/organization email address.

Comment: @tehlexx I retried to download the official version "15.0" and found another error "Unable to connect to Open Agent Failed to start /recorder/silkRecorder.exe after a time out of 180 seconds". That's so annoying.

Comment: When this happens, is there a `openAgent.exe` process running then? In some cases we've seen the RMI communication to cause issues like that. Can you please try to bind the RMI registry to `localhost`? The process is outlined at http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/topic/com.borland.silktest.silk4j.doc/SILKTEST-163D6206-CONFIGURINGOPENAGENTLABMANAGERVM-TSK.html?resultof=%22%72%6d%69%22%20 - you'll need to do it for `agent.properties` and `recorder.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run only silk test recorder from start programs menu to see of the recorder is fine.

Alternatively you can make sure if firewall exceptions are added for open agent and for may be recorder as well